# Is it professionally acceptable to consider extreme/radical political orientation in a hiring process?

Tags: hiring-process

In general, political orientation should not be asked and/or affect the hiring process. However, if one publicly advocates radical parties, oppressive regimes (such as Iran or China), or extremists what is the consensus and professional stand about considering this as a negative factor in the hiring process?

I am talking about extreme cases, for example, hardliners who believe it is okay to kill an atheist whenever they can---not usual political leaning. Also, I am not saying that they directly state that they want to kill someone or such, but they explicitly advocate groups doing that.

**Update**: They behaved fine during the interview and are capable of doing what the position needs. This knowledge of political orientation became clear during an *internship* period, not in the workplace but in several social events and actively in their social network profiles. Now, this question raised when they applied for a longer-term employment.

Comment: How a person behaves during an interview is part of the process. Are they nice to the receptionist, do they have basic manners, etc. Frankly, if North Korea came up in an interview I’d find that very odd (well, except for specific national security postings). So, was this during an interview, checking references, or what?

Comment: Do you think it will impact their work?

Comment: When someone openly promotes any radical ideas (political, religious etc.) during the hiring process, you can expect them to do the same to future colleagues..

Comment: Based on what you wrote, my assumption is that these far-right political opinions and beliefs are in opposition to your own. Let me ask you a question; is it OK to discriminate based on political opinions and beliefs, even if they contradict your own or those of the majority?

Comment: @TomTom They behaved fine during the interview and are capable of doing what the position needs. This knowledge of political orientation became clear during an interview period, not in the workplace but in several social events and actively in their social network profiles. Now, this question raised when they applied for longer-term employment. I am not directly responsible for making decision on the matter and this is more or less a hypothetical question from my perspective.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie most likely, it won't.

Comment: @JonCuster please refer to my reply to TomTom, it covers your questions too.

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes, your assumption is right. The opinions and beliefs are in opposition to my own. And, it's not okay to discriminate based on political opinions. But I brought up examples like Iran where, for example, hardliners believe it is okay to kill an atheist whenever they can. I am talking about such extreme cases, not usual political leaning. Also, I am not saying that they directly state that they want to kill someone or such, but they explicitly advocate groups doing that.

Comment: You _should_ remove "far-right" from the question (and make it more general and balanced; say, you could mention Iran and Venezuela). _Then_ the Q could be at least attempted to be answered fairly.

Comment: Would you apply the same standards to support of the Chinese regime as to support of the North Korean?

Comment: @Zeus fair point. I will do that.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- any oppressive/violent regime is the same here. Those are just a few examples of many.

Comment: @rs.29 Fair point. I updated the question. I was specific to the case I am talking about.

Comment: "okay to kill [a person]" seems to transcend politics.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm going to attempt to answer this in a political neutral way. I don't believe these types of questions are specific to the far-right. There are certainly business owners who are equally cautious about those on the far-left.

You will not find consensus on this issue.

There are those that believe that holding certain political beliefs means you automatically should be disqualified from being employed.

Others believe people should be assessed on merit and capability to do a job only.

It is of my opinion that you need to assess people on their merit, and you should give people the benefit of the doubt. If people are shown to act in a manner that is divisive, regardless of the political leaning, that is behaviour that should be moderated.

I also find it's important to note that there is one can hold firm ideological beliefs without subscribing to extremist narrative. An example is that some interpretations/quotes of the bible call for violent action against different categories of people, but almost all christians abhor violence.

Comment: The tricky part with "merit and capability to do a job" is that it can lead to very different conclusions depending on where you set the boundary of those criteria. If Bob is a fast and reliable widget maker, but his political activities lead to a customer boycott of the business, does that count into assessments of his merit/capability?

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent I absolutely agree with you on that. It's a very very tricky problem that, as a society, we are really struggling with. A lot of companies are very willing to fire people to placate the mob, which I have severe ethical problems with. But I'm under no illusions that doing such a thing can represent a sane business decision.

Comment: In general I'd agree, but in practice and given relatively recent events, when said 'political beliefs' involve the notion that it's acceptable to storm the capitol just because you don't want to accept that your candidate lost, I wouldn't want to work with them.

Comment: @Shadur I don't think you should make sweeping generalisations that all of those on (what you consider) the far right, are insurrectionists. Also, as a hiring manager, your personal feelings towards someone are secondary to their ability to do their job and work well with others.

Comment: I suspect business owners who are cautious about those or the far left is because they might fear successful labour organisation and subsequently increased labour costs.  Whether that is an acceptable reason not to hire someone is a different question, but I can see it happening more readily than blocking hires of people with far right views.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie That's very much part of the problem though, somebody who _literally_ demonizes ("DemonRats" instead of "Democrats") another group of people - half of the country in this case - _will_ create a hostile work environment. OP made it pretty clear we're not talking about someone who just votes for another party, but about extremists. Big chance that a coworker votes differently, and killing coworkers is a no-no.

Comment: @R.Schmitz There is no indication that this worker has actually demonized their coworkers at all. In fact, the question demonstrates that OP was completely unaware of the employee's political stance until their looked at their Facebook profile.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Wrong, OP says _"in several social events and actively in their social network profiles."_ If somebody wants me dead, I don't want to work with them. If they behave professionally at work or not is the least of my concerns at that point.

Comment: @R.Schmitz "Somebody wants me dead". Who is demonizing who here?

Comment: @gregorycurrie When one 'side' of the political debate unironically wears T-shirts like 'Civil War, Jan 6 2021' or 'Rope, Tree, Journalist - Some Assembly Required' and stages an insurrection, and *the vast majority of that side either tacitly or openly endorses it* I'm going to assume *any* member of that side is potentially life-threateningly hostile until proven otherwise.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I'm assuming you didn't read the part of the question where it says _"I am not saying that they directly state that they want to kill someone or such, but they explicitly advocate groups doing that"_. Because otherwise, that would be some hardcore victim blaming.

Comment: @Shadur The Woke Left is no better, in case you missed BLM riots burning down half the country last year. Painting radicalism as a Right-wing thing only is misleading.

Comment: @shadur CNN reporter" These protests are very peaceful" Buildings burning behind him on camera. Absolute BRUH moment

Comment: `almost all christians abhor violence` - Please cite a reference for this statement. This seems like an unqualified remark based on your own experience.

Comment: There is a difference between holding opinions such as  yes the second amendment does mean  and individual right to to own  weapons and advocating sectarian violence which is highly ileagal.

For example in parts of the UK (NI) wearing a football shirt is grounds for gross misconduct.

Answer (score 16):

I would say in general that this person's inability to keep these views to themselves *during the hiring process* is a strong indication, regardless of which side of the issue they are on, that they will bring them up, maybe repeatedly, in the office. I also think it shows lack of professional judgement on what's appropriate to discuss in a professional environment.

Therefore, they will spend time arguing and distracting coworkers espousing these beliefs and will contribute to a toxic workplace, in addition may impact other people's attention where they may then stop working to argue with this person, or find it difficult to concentrate while they bring up these views in the office.

I think as a rule of thumb, if you have learned somehow this person's extremist views, in such a short time frame, your team members will as well, and it will not be a good cultural fit.

If this happened to me... If the candidate seemed good, professionally, I would talk to them and say... Look....it's been this much time and I have been made aware you have a very divisive view on this topic. This topic has nothing to do with work. I'm interested in hiring you, but if you bring these issues up in the office, as it is a sensitive subject, it will very likely make other team members uncomfortable. I am comfortable moving forward with this but you need to be aware we have a policy against discussing politics in the office and I'm concerned, as our discussions so far have already made your views known.

Update - he mentioned in the comments it came about from social media activity and not in the workplace. Very different scenario... An argument can still be made that one needs to be careful about their social media presence as they can be interpreted as a representative of an organization, but I think this is much less severe. If he has kept it out of the office and it's only been found by scrutinizing his social media, then I think absolutely he should be able to be part of the workplace, so long as he is able to keep those views to his private life and not in the office... If it's a problem that those are on social media, maybe your company develops a policy on this and addresses it, but I think that's much less serious than my initial interpretation that this came up out of his own discussions during hiring process

Comment: +1 voice of reason. Keep his personal ideology separate from his qualifications for work unless evidence dictates elsewise

Answer (score 11):

There are lots of colleagues who will have to work with the person, and that is what you need to take into account. Plus future colleagues. For example, if you talk to a candidate and you think "we don't have any muslims as employees right now, but if we hire this person, then hiring a muslim would be a problem". If that's what you think, and you think you should be free to hire people whatever religion they have, then this person is a problem.

Or if you think "I wouldn't want this person employed if a young woman is there as well", that's a problem. Or "this person thinks anyone who gets vaccinated is stupid", that's a problem. So you *can* professionally reject someone because of their political or otherwise views.

Comment: Political views are no different to religion in terms of discrimination protection. You can turn it around and say "if we hire this muslim now, it would be a problem to hire a right-winger later". Does it work?

Comment: @Zeus That "it would be a problem" needs unpacking: which of the two candidates is making it a problem? "We can't hire B because they hate A" and "we can't hire A because B hates them" are not equal and opposite scenarios.

Comment: @Zeus At least in the US this isn't the case.  Some states protect employees from political discrimination, but it isn't a federally protected class and many states don't include it as a protected class.

Comment: @Zeus In both cases though, the Muslim employee is passive - it is the right-wing employee (or candidate) who would be an active threat. So no, it's not equal in both your cases. If you were to equate a right-winger with a radical Muslim who believed in armed jihad against their neighbours, *then* you would have an equal situation.

Comment: @Graham, yes, of course, I assumed a symmetric case: the Muslim in question is a good employee but supports radical jihad in social media, network profiles etc, like in the Q. Yet it doesn't involve any direct threats, least of all to the neighbours, again like in the Q; just a general (even if vocal) "support".

Answer (score 6):

I mostly agree with the previous answers, but there is an additional point I think needs to be considered.
That is, what position is that person applying for?

The OP said they learned about that person’s beliefs from events and social media and generally they keep their views out of the workplace.
So for a regular office job, while their beliefs might be a factor, they shouldn't automatically disqualify that person.

If the job is more public, customer-facing position (e.g. a community manager) their opinions could cause big problem as their private views will be associated with the company by (potiential) customers.

Answer (score 2):

Extreme worldviews are a risk that can lead to a toxic workplace environment and even violence:
https://www.everbridge.com/blog/five-types-workplace-violence/

Some years ago I had a coworker who happened to be an extremist, and while he behaved perfectly professionally in front of the project managers, he was a bully in their backs. His behaviour impacted my and my colleague's performance really badly. I also have to say that the managers where also pretty incompetent, and believed the problem of bullying is the victim.

Also people can recoment their friends and aquitances to apply for a job in your conpany, so the extremist could bring other extremists in your workplace.

On the other hand you have to be carefull about who you consider to be extremist/radical, because you can end being unfair and/or end loosing someone who happened to be a good fit. As an example, vegans and capitalists can be extremists, but a lot of them are not.

So I would say it's ok to be cautious if you have this information, it's ok if you don't want to take the risk, but also  evaluate only to not to hire this person by ideology if you have very good reasons to believe they are an extremist.